# Generate hierarchical path

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child, maximo, hierarchical-query

I have a `classstructure` table:

```
create table classstructure (classstructureid number(8,0), classificationid varchar2(25), parent number(8,0));

insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1001, 'FLEET', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1002, 'LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1004, 'MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1022, 'ACTIVETRANSPORTATION', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1023, 'FACILITYWALKWAY', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1024, 'TRAIL', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1085, 'SIDEWALK', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1091, 'SDWRAMP', 1085);
commit;

select * from classstructure;

CLASSSTRUCTUREID CLASSIFICATIONID              PARENT
---------------- ------------------------- ----------
            1001 FLEET                               
            1002 LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE                1001
            1004 MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE               1001

            1022 ACTIVETRANSPORTATION                
            1023 FACILITYWALKWAY                 1022
            1024 TRAIL                           1022
            1085 SIDEWALK                        1022
            1091 SDWRAMP                         1085
```

I would like to collapse the records down to hierarchy paths:

```
HIERARCHYPATH
---------------------------
FLEET \ LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE
FLEET \ MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE 

ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ FACILITYWALKWAY
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ TRAIL
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK \ SDWRAMP
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: I realized after I wrote this question that I should have included rows that are the first level of the hierarchy. [More info in my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67903948/10936066). I'll leave the question as-is...I just wanted to point that out for any Maximo users who might have found my original question and this answer a confusing. (It was my mistake, not Barbaros Özhan's mistake.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys_connect_by_path()`( since `Oracle 10g Release 2` ) function :

```
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(classificationid, ' \ '),' \ ') as hierarchypath
  from classstructure c
 where parent is not null
 start with parent is null
connect by prior classstructureid = parent;

HIERARCHYPATH
--------------------------------------
FLEET \ LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE
FLEET \ MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ FACILITYWALKWAY
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ TRAIL
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK \ SDWRAMP
```

Comment: I realized after I wrote this question that I should have included rows that are the first level of the hierarchy. [More info in my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67903948/10936066). I'll leave the question as-is...I just wanted to point that out for any Maximo users who might have found my original question and this answer a confusing. (It was my mistake, not Barbaros Özhan's mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**

I realized after I wrote this question that I should have included rows that are the first level of the hierarchy.

So here's an updated version of @Barbaros' query. I removed the WHERE clause.

```
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(classificationid, ' \ '),' \ ') as hierarchypath
from maximo.classstructure
start with parent is null
connect by prior classstructureid = parent;
```

---

**Edit 2:**

For bonus points, here's a version of the query that also includes Maximo's USE WITH objects (grouped by & concatenated):

```
select 
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(cl.classificationid, ' \ '),' \ ') as hierarchypath,
    cl.classstructureid,
    cl.description,
    uw.usewith
from 
    maximo.classstructure cl
left join
    (
    select 
        classstructureid, 
        listagg(objectname,', ') within group(order by objectname) as usewith
    from 
        maximo.classusewith
    group by 
        classstructureid
    ) uw
    on cl.classstructureid = uw.classstructureid
start with parent is null
connect by prior cl.classstructureid = parent
order by
    hierarchypath
```

[image]

---

**Edit 3:**

On a side note, here's how to group-by-concat USEWITH in a **subquery** (for scenarios where we can't use the JOIN clause, only the WHERE clause).

Of course, the subquery performance is a lot worse than a proper join. We'd want to use a join instead of a subquery whenever possible.

```
select 
    cl.classstructureid,
    cl.description,
   
    (select 
        listagg(objectname,', ') within group(order by objectname) as usewith
    from 
        maximo.classusewith
    group by 
        classstructureid
    having 
        classstructureid = cl.classstructureid
    ) as usewith

from 
    maximo.classstructure cl
order by
    description
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same sort of query can be applied to Maximo **asset hiearchy** too (not just classifications):

```
select 
    assetnum,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(assetnum, ' \ '),' \ ') as path,
    level
from 
    maximo.asset
start with parent is null
connect by prior assetnum = parent
```

[image]

I also added a LEVEL column that gives us the **level number**.